# difference between 連載 and 順次

Tags: definitions, word-choice

I usually see the word 連載 pertaining to articles or books in a series. However, when I read 順次 I was confused (I saw this is a technical article). They seem to both hold the meaning "serial" or "consecutive" or "in series". Is 連載 exclusively used when referring to books, articles, novels, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and 連載 is an action noun or a する verb, while 順次 basically works as an adverb.

Comment: Okay, I think that answers my question!

Comment: You can say, 連ドラ (serial drama), 連投 (pitching in consecutive games), 連休 (consecutive holidays), 連峰 (mountain range), 連だこ (kite train), and so on.

Comment: I was told that 連 holds the meaning of 乗る. So when referring to a series that depend on the previous instance, 連 should be used. Does this seem valid?

Comment: The 連 means series, continuity, link, connection, and so on. The 載 holds the meaning of 乗せる or to load.